# jQuery: getting the last li from clicking a link and doing a actionf or it

Tags: jquery

I have a minified version of what I actually have but its the same method, what I'm struggling to work out is when I click on a more link within the LI I need to set a scrolltobottom bottom function but I cannot work out how to do the condition so if I click and its the last LI do this. Any ideas?

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="truncated_text_wrapper">
      <div class="truncated_text" style="display: none;">sending this test message sending this test message sending... (<a data-action="expand_text" href="#">more</a>)
      </div>
      <div style="" class="complete_text">sending this test message sending this test message sending this test message sending this test message sending this test message sending this test message sending this test message sending this test message (<a data-action="shrink_text" href="#">less</a>)
       </div>
      </div>
      <a class="link" href="#">more</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="truncated_text_wrapper">
      <div class="truncated_text" style="display: none;">sending this test message sending this test message sending... (<a data-action="expand_text" href="#">more</a>)
      </div>
      <div style="" class="complete_text">sending this test message sending this test message sending this test message sending this test message sending this test message sending this test message sending this test message sending this test message (<a data-action="shrink_text" href="#">less</a>)
       </div>
      </div>
      <a class="link" href="#">more</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="truncated_text_wrapper">
      <div class="truncated_text" style="display: none;">sending this test message sending this test message sending... (<a data-action="expand_text" href="#">more</a>)
      </div>
      <div style="" class="complete_text">sending this test message sending this test message sending this test message sending this test message sending this test message sending this test message sending this test message sending this test message (<a data-action="shrink_text" href="#">less</a>)
       </div>
      </div>
      <a class="link" href="#">more</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="truncated_text_wrapper">
      <div class="truncated_text" style="display: none;">sending this test message sending this test message sending... (<a data-action="expand_text" href="#">more</a>)
      </div>
      <div style="" class="complete_text">sending this test message sending this test message sending this test message sending this test message sending this test message sending this test message sending this test message sending this test message (<a data-action="shrink_text" href="#">less</a>)
       </div>
      </div>
      <a class="link" href="#">more</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The JS i have worked on is the following:

```
var carousel = setupCarousel();

  $(".truncated_text_wrapper .truncated_text a[data-action=expand_text]").live("click", function(){
    $(this).parents(".truncated_text").hide();
    $(this).parents(".truncated_text_wrapper").find(".complete_text").show();
        if($(this).siblings().length===0) {
            carousel.scrollToBottom();
            console.log('moved');
        }
        return false;  
  });
```

You will see I attempted if siblings scrolltobottom - I only want to action that if it's the last LI that the more button is clicked.

Comment: I think you've minified your problem too much. What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: sorry early morning :) i have updated with the JS i have, what im ideally looking for is to add an if statement to scroll to bottom if its the last li when you click that particular more link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
$('ul').find('li a').on('click', function(){
   window.scrollTo(0, document.scrollHeight);
});
```

Or only the last LI:

```
$('ul').find('li:last-child a').on('click', function(){
   window.scrollTo(0, document.scrollHeight);
});
```

Or animate scroll to the clicked element:

```
$('ul').find('li:last-child a').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault() // this time you want the anchor to do nothing
   var elem = this;
   $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(elem.href).offset().top }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Martijn, i update with the JS i had - i just need an if statement so if its the last li and only when you click on the last read link